# Negative margins and borders

Tags: css, cross-browser, margin

I have some images I want to stack using negative margins.  However, since stacking images without clearly defined boundaries can be visually confusing, I figured I should add a border around them.  Strangely, the even though the images stack correctly, their borders end up underneath the previous element.

Why is this the behavior I'm getting, and is there a way to make the borders appear at their intuitive level?

```css
#second {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

img {
  border: 5px ridge green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"><img id="second" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"></div>
```

EDIT: On Firefox, this is what it looks like: 
[image: firefox-borders]

Comment: On Chrome here, the second image overlapse the first with it's border. What browser are you using ? EDIT: On Internet Explorer 11 it doesn't work.

Comment: On Chrome it looks fine but Firefox shows the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's Firefox.

Comment: Post a picture of the problem in Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue doesn't appear in Chrome but does in Firefox and IE. The easy solution appears to just do something like set the position of the images to relative:

```css
#second {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

img {
  border: 5px ridge green;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"><img id="second" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"></div>
```

Comment: Also to ensure the overlapping maybe will suggest the use of `z-index`

Comment: @DaniP - for some situations that might be needed but it doesn't look like it's necessary here.

Comment: Agree just wanted to point that as an option if gets more img involved

Answer (score 3):

You may use transform to force drawing of borders too in FF:

[image: ff screenshot]

```css
#second {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

img {
  border: 5px ridge green;
  display: block;
  }

/* FF debug*/
div + div img {
  transform:scale(1);/* transform + anyvalue that does nothing new forces the layout to be redrawn */
}
div {float:left;
  margin:1em;
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"><img id="second" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"></div>
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"><img id="second" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG/312px-RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.JPG" height="100" width="auto"></div>
```